# form select option causing javascript to fail

Tags: javascript

I've got the following javascript function that reloads the form once a select option is chosen.  I'm using this to pull data from database into each additional select dropdown based on which option they chose in the first, second, etc.

```
function reloadForm(form)
{
var cat=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
if (cat.length > 0) { var cat1 = '&cat=' + cat; }                    

var subcat1=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].value;
if (subcat1.length > 0) { var subcat2 = '&subcat=' + subcat1; } 

self.location = 'index.php<?php echo $webvars; ?>' + cat1;
}
```

But here is my problem, once I add the subcat variable in, the script stops working.  I don't understand why?

### Below is my html/php code so far.... just in case someone needs it.

```
$product_sku = $db1q->query("SELECT sku FROM Inventory_SKU WHERE id = $id");
if ($product_sku->num_rows > 0) { 
while ($row = $product_sku->fetch_assoc()) { echo '<h2>CONNECTING '. $row['sku'] .' TO PRODUCT</h2>'; }
}

echo '<div class="margin20">';                                
echo '<form name="connectsku" action="index.php'. $webvars .'" method="POST">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="connect_sku" value="1">';                               




echo '<select name="cat" onchange="reloadForm(this.form)"><option value="">SELECT CATEGORY</option>';
foreach ($db1q->query("SELECT c.id, c.name,s.name as section FROM Product_Categories as c JOIN Product_Sections as s ON c.section = s.id") as $catdd) {
echo '<option value="'. $catdd['id'] .'">'. $catdd['name'] .'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';




if ((isset($cat)) && ($cat != "")) {                                               
echo '<select name="subcat" onchange="reloadForm(this.form)">
<option value="">Select SUBCAT</option>';
foreach ($db1q->query("SELECT id, name FROM Product_Sub_Category ") as $subcatdd) {
echo '<option value="'. $subcatdd['id'] .'">'. $subcatdd['name'] .'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";

}




if ((isset($subcat)) && ($subcat != "")) {
echo "<select name='subcat3' ><option value=''>Select one</option>";
foreach ($dbo->query($quer3) as $noticia) {
echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcat2]'>$noticia[subcat2]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}                             

echo '<input type="submit" value="MOVE TO NEXT STEP">';
echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
```

### CONSOLE LOG

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'oninput' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.php?p1=inventorymanagement&p2=ConnectSKU&id=3:65)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
index.php?p1=inventorymanagement&p2=ConnectSKU&id=3:238 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at reloadForm (index.php?p1=inventorymanagement&p2=ConnectSKU&id=3:238)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (index.php?p1=inventorymanagement&p2=ConnectSKU&id=3:248)
```

Subcat Select field is hidden until $cat is definied by url update.  Could it be because there is nothing to pull from on the page thats causing the error?  Is there a line of code I can add to check to see if subcat has a valid value or exists because running the subcat portion?

Comment: I had this working on another page but then when i copied it over to this page, something changed and now it wont work.  But if I take out the subcat section of the script, the first part works.  I'm going to end up having 4 different dropdowns in this so I need this to work.

Comment: What is inside `$webvars` exactly ?

Comment: is subcat also the name of an element ID in your form? JS may be getting confused by conflicting variable names

Comment: all that does is get the variables from the url via $_SERVER and echo them out.  I use that to not have to type in all the variables in each url if I'm adding to them.    In this example its `?p1=inventorymanagement&p2=ConnectSKU`

Comment: I believe it's your .= (dot equals) in the subcat code.

Comment: I changed it to `var subcat1=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].value;
if (subcat1.length > 0) { var subcat2 = '&subcat=' + subcat1; } ` with same result.

Comment: @GordonKushner - no its not.  Sorry, that was a typo on here.  Thats not in code.

Comment: I've added my html/php script so that everyone can see how I'm pulling data

Comment: So you mean the error occurs when you try `'index.php<?php echo $webvars; ?>' + cat1 + subcat;` ? Do a `console.log(subcat);` and show us the result.

Comment: console log added.  So maybe its because subcat is undefined because theres nothing to choose from until cat is selected.  Is there a javascript line of code I can add to only add subcat if subcat has a value to add?  Subcat select field doesnt even show on page until cat is selected.

Comment: @GordonKushner -  it does...php webvar sets that.  That part works if subcat part of the code isnt there....so thats not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it was because the select field for subcat was not being generated because I had a condition that it only generated if cat was set.  I ended up always showing it and just "hide" it using html if category isnt set.  That way javascript could at least detect it was there.  This ended up fixing the entire problem.